# Why does "UInt64(1 << 63)" crash?

Tags: swift

```
println(UInt8(1 << 7)) // OK
println(UInt16(1 << 15)) // OK
println(UInt32(1 << 31)) // OK
println(UInt64(1 << 63)) // Crash
```

I would like to understand why this happens for UInt64 only. Thanks!

Edit:
To make matters more confusing, the following all work:

```
println(1 << UInt8(7))
println(1 << UInt16(15))
println(1 << UInt32(31))
println(1 << UInt64(63))
```

My guess is that an intermediate result produced by computing 1 << 63 is too large.

Comment: Another swift type inferrer issue :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `println(UInt64(1) << UInt64(63))`.

The type inferrer didn't do its job well and decided that **`1 << 63` is a `UInt32`** and used this function: `func <<(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32`

`println(1 << UInt64(63))` works because the compiler knows that since `UInt64(63)` is a `UInt64`, then **the integer literal `1` is inferred to be a `UInt64`**, therefore the operation results in a `UInt64` and is not out of bounds.